# Video allow crossposting for pages requires publish_pages permission in Live mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook graph api to post the following call:

```
POST: http://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/{video_id}
allow_crossposting_for_pages = [{"page_id" : {fb_page_id}, "allow" : true }]
```

This works fine when the App is in Dev mode, but when switching the App to Live mode I'm getting the following error.  "(#200) The permission(s) publish_pages are not available. It could because either they are deprecated or need to be approved by App Review."

I've tried requesting publish_pages permissions for my App but as expected FB rejects it saying this is not required to grant crossposting permissions.  And with no surprise provides no help in trying to figure out if this is a defect or some other weird problem on my end.

As anyone else run into this or a similar problem when trying to run the App in Live mode?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#Updating clearly states, _“To update a Page video, a Page access token with the `publish_pages` permission is required.”_ - so I’d try to submit again, and explicitly quote this to the reviewer …

Comment: I see that now... thanks.  I guess we'll see were this goes.  The Facebook App Review process has been nothing but painful.